# Activate objects that are hit - Blender Fracture Modifier Build

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to do a cgi door break effect, and I am having trouble with the collision. I am using the blender fracture modifier build and have so far been able to break the door. I am using a set up in which the object that is to be broken is animated until the other object comes flying at it. The problem is, once the object ceases to being animated, the entire door falls down due to gravity when I only want the shards to. I am using constraints and need a way to only let the shards of the door that is hit fall.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the object flying into the door to be a trigger and the door should be animated and triggered. Both settings are in rigidbody physics Panel in the FM build. This way only the shards the incoming object will touch should be activated.